# Почему не выводятся переменные в консоли?C#

Tags: c#, консоль

У меня есть 4 переменных:int, double, char string.
Все эти переменные я хочу вывести в одну строчку в консоли
Я конвертирую int и double в string, но почему-то выводится только int, а остальных нету

```cs
int sum = 1 + 1;
double div = 5 / 2;
string sumOfStrings = "abra" + "cadabra";
char charSecond = 's';

Console.WriteLine(sum.ToString(), div.ToString(), sumOfStrings, charSecond);
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что это не так работает. [Первый аргумент - строка формата.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-8.0#system-console-writeline(system-string-system-object-system-object-system-object)) У вас в строке нет шаблонов `{0} {1} {2}`, поэтому остальные аргументы в эту строку не попадают и просто игнорируются.

Используйте современное форматирование - интерполяцию строк:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"{sum}, {div}, {sumOfStrings}, {charSecond}");
```